# Java servlets, Should I upload the files containing source code or upload a compiled version?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm pretty new to the java world.

I want to know a very basic info.
When I create a web application using java servlets, then upload it to the server. I would upload the files containing the source code or I would upload only a compiled version of them to the server to run online?

Comment: Java class files,without source code the war will properly deployed.each WAR file can contains servlets, JSPs, a deployment descriptor, and related resource files.

Comment: DV for showing no basic research effort. Please have a look into [ask].

Comment: @Fildor,
I did a basic search effort but didn't find a trusted answer because I'm pretty new to java. The question may seem easy for you because you are not new to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to build a WAR of the project. You can do this

in eclipse: right click on the project, Click "Export", and choose war file in the dialog (and mention, the destination, name and all)
via ant using the war task

The ant option is better because when you have multiple developers on the project and the code is in version control, it is easier to get the project automatically (using ant) and build a war. (you have version control, don't you?)

But this is more of an operational difference (albeit an important one) but the war created in either way are same

Deploy the war to the server

You can manually copy the war file to the $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps directory (See the "Creating and Deploying a WAR File" section on [this article](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat.html?page=5))

You can use the Tomcat 6 ["Manager" Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Comment: Thank you.
But, can the war file be rolled back again to the source code by anyway or it's impossible?

Comment: It's easy to unpack the WAR file - it is just a Zip file with a specific layout. On Mac or Linux, you can just call "unzip" on the file. Unfortunately, that doesn't get you the source files, just the compiled .class files, so you'll need a decompiler to be able to read java code, and it won't be the same as your original source code

Comment: That's what I need to know. 
Thank you